# How to clone Google Container Cluster / Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

As in title. I want to clone (create a copy of existing cluster).

If it's not possible to copy/clone Google Container Engine cluster, then how to clone Kubernetes cluster?

If that's not possible, is there a way to dump the whole cluster config?

#### Note:

I try to modify the cluster's configs by calling:

```
kubectl apply -f some-resource.yaml
```

But nothing stops me/other employee modifying the cluster by running:

```
kubectl edit service/resource
```

Or setting properties from command line `kubectl` calls.

Answer (score 13):

I'm using a bash script from CoreOS team, with small adjustments, that works pretty good. By default it's excluding the kube-system namespace, but you can adjust this if you need. Also you can add or remove the resources you want to copy.

```
for ns in $(kubectl get ns --no-headers | cut -d " " -f1); do
  if { [ "$ns" != "kube-system" ]; }; then
  kubectl --namespace="${ns}" get --export -o=json svc,rc,rs,deployments,cm,secrets,ds,statefulsets,ing | \
jq '.items[] |
    select(.type!="kubernetes.io/service-account-token") |
    del(
        .spec.clusterIP,
        .metadata.uid,
        .metadata.selfLink,
        .metadata.resourceVersion,
        .metadata.creationTimestamp,
        .metadata.generation,
        .status,
        .spec.template.spec.securityContext,
        .spec.template.spec.dnsPolicy,
        .spec.template.spec.terminationGracePeriodSeconds,
        .spec.template.spec.restartPolicy
    )' >> "./my-cluster.json"
  fi
done
```

To restore it on another cluster, you have to execute `kubectl create -f ./my-cluster.json`

Comment: Thanks. I guess there's no a one liner for it? Is there a way to distinguish a hand set values from defaults?

Comment: that is the correct answer.
worked like charm :)

Comment: update: In gcp I had to remove the "--export"

Answer (score 2):

You can now create/clone an existing cluster,
On the Clusters page, click on create cluster and choose an existing cluster. But remember, this will not clone the api-resources you may have to use a third party tool such as Velero to help you backup the resources.

Here are some useful links

- [Cluster Creation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster)
- [Velero](https://velero.io/docs/v1.2.0/)
- [Medium Article on How to use Velero](https://blog.doit-intl.com/google-kubernetes-engine-cluster-migration-with-velero-4a140b018f32)